# Is there an include_once function or macro in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there an `include_once` method in julia to `include` a file only once, like `#pragma once` or `#ifndef` in C++?

Comment: No, this is not how Julia code should be organized. Include a file only once, but `using` the module in that file multiple times.

Comment: I know that `using` module is the better way for reusing code. It is faster than `include` if precompiled too. However there maybe situations where one needs `include`. I have several macros that evaluate to global scope (generating functions for example). If I put these macros in a module, they will be evaluated to the module scope, not the global scope where they are called. How could I organize these macros in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This answer elaborates a little on the comments. It is for beginners like me who stumbled across this post trying to figure out the basics of file organization, (before getting to slightly more advanced topics like module and package creation) and wondering why there isn't an easy way to do something like C++'s header guards.

The key is to include everything in the "lowest-level" file once, and nowhere else.  An example: Assume you have main.jl, A.jl, B.jl, and C.jl. Assume:

-main.jl needs A.jl and B.jl and C.jl.

-A.jl needs B.jl and C.jl.

-B.jl needs C.jl.

The key here is to NOT use include statements in A.jl and B.jl.  Instead, you find the “lowest-level” file, in this case main.jl, and put all the include statements there, in the correct order.  In main.jl:

```
include("C.jl")
include("B.jl")
include("A.jl")
```

And then NO include statements ANYWHERE else.  For more on this, see https://www.reddit.com/r/Julia/comments/hwxpgm/beginner_question_files_modules_and_include_vs/, particularly user a5sk6n’s outstanding answer in the comments.